# Can Vite Multipage Apps handle Path Params?

Tags: vue.js, vite

I'm trying to convert my app from using the Vue Cli to build to Vite. It's a simple multipage app with 2 endpoints `admin` and `portal` my directory structure looks like...

```
| vite.config.js
|     - admin
|          index.html
|          App.vue
|     - portal
|          index.html
|          App.vue
| index.html
```

And my vite config looks like...

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import { resolve } from 'path'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],
  server: {
    port: 8080
  },
  build: {
    outDir: '../dist',
    sourcemap: true,
    rollupOptions: {
      input: {
        main: resolve(__dirname, 'index.html'),
        admin: resolve(__dirname, '/admin/index.html'),
        portal: resolve(__dirname, '/portal/index.html')
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Which works well for `/admin` and `/portal` endpoints, but I'm wondering if this can handle path params such as `/portal/randomstring`?

Comment: Each page would need a router or a subpage for the path params.

Comment: @tony19 I'm handling the path param on the page by parsing it off, the problem is when I go to `/portal/randomstring` it loads the base page instead of the portal page.

Comment: How are you handling `randomstring` on `portal/index.html`? Put a client side router there (e.g., `vue-router`). Or a subpage (e.g., `portal/randomstring.html`).

Comment: I'm just grabbing the url and parsing out the bit I need which is the random string. I'll try putting it behind a router and see what that does. Thanks for the suggestion!